# PHP encrypt / decrypt huge string text for MySQL DB

Tags: php

I have multiple text files that are very large, and adding them on MySQL is 100 text = is over 1MB (this is just an example) and I was thinking if is possible to encrypt them so I can make the text shorter so will use less MySQL DB space? and when I'm getting them back from MySQL to be able to decrypt so I can see the real text?

I try to use base_64 and other gzip compress, but all of them is making the size much bigger than original.

How can I compress the text files (encrypt / decrypt)?

Comment: Can you not just store the URL to the file and refer to the URL when you need it?

Comment: What im trying to store is some json files, but because they are very large i need a way to be able to encrypt them so the size will be smaller. but the same time to be able to decrypt them so i can see the original json file to, im searching for 2 days for a way but no luck...

Comment: what you want is compression. Don't get confused with compression vs encryption. There is a distinction between them

Comment: BASE 64 IS NOT ENCRYPTION!  The base64 format is purely for converting binary data into a format that can be safely sent over text-only networking channels.  It does nothing to protect the contents of your file from snoopers and was never intended to.  Please learn the difference between encoding and encryption

Answer (score 0):

you can use InnoDB (engine) compression. As you've asked, it is the same as ZIP compression

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no :) You can't reduce text files using encryption but you can compress text data in database. [InnoDB compression example in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the ability to manipulate .zip files.

You could save your text into a .zip file, and simply store the filename in the database.  This would save a lot of MySQL database space, but you will need some way to generate unique filenames, and somewhere to store those files.

At least they would be zipped, to save as much disk space as possible...

Comment: This should give you all the info you need on reading from and writing to .zip files:  http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make DB shorter, you can save large texts as files (on local server, CDN, or remote servers). Keep only *filenames* in DB and *additional information* about texts.

In result, you will be able to use the database in your application and read files from hard disks.